# Need to set timeout(s) in nodeJS, what could be right and optimize way?

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

I had a requirement, where I need to perform a task after 2 minutes for N requests, when certain condition meet.

I am just curious to know what could be the right and optimize way without compromising the application performance, as this could be lead to 100ths 1000ths and more request, creating setTimeout() against each will def. be worse.

Kindly, expert advice needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-cron. Here is an example.

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
var scheduleMinute=2;

 cron.schedule(" */"+scheduleMinute+" * * * *", function() {
 console.log('will execute after every 2 minutes');
});
```

To get a detail idea you can see here.
[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Comment: What would be the impact of it when 100ths or more, schedule registered? How it impact on system/os and again calling of callbacks same times? etc etc. Can you elaborate it?